# javascript ajax login form handling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im working on an ajax form to show errors without reloading the page. So if everything is good, the user we be redirected to `home.php`. At the moment the user will also be redirected when there is an error.

This is my code so far:

**index.php:**

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("formVal");
var formData = new FormData(elements); 

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            window.location.replace("/index.php");
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("post", "login.php"); 
    xmlHttp.send(formData); 
}  
</script>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!$user->logUser($$_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'not ok';
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: You are always redirected to /home.php because you always return http 200 and you don't deal with the content of the response. In login.php, you should return http 401 if the authentication failed, and not just 'not ok'.

Answer (score 1):

Remove loop from the code and pass `elements` in `FormData()` because passing `element` will take all the fields inside the form

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("formVal");
var formData = new FormData(elements);
```

Comment: What is the loop that I should remove?

Comment: that you have mentioned in your question `for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)`

Comment: I changed my code, can u tell if it is changed correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Throw a 401 error if it fails login, this will stop the redirect.

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (!$user->logUser($$_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
        exit;
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there also a way that I can show what kind of error it is? Like if the username is correct but the password is incorrect

Comment: @web-stars if it is something the public see's. You do not want to tell them that, just say something is wrong.

Comment: Oké, thanks. I will try to do the rest of jquery myself :)

Comment: @web-stars any particular reason you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score -1):

do you know jquery ?
jquery w3 school search on google
avaible

```
$('#data-div-id').load('www.sdasd .php ? or whatevver');

    function tmp_func_sil_ok(e){
  $.ajax({type:"GET",url:"go.php",data:{'snf_sil':e},success: function(e){msg_("<h3>Başarılı</h3>");}});
}
```

Comment: In w3school is no answer for my question

Comment: a lot of  be will on working ajax code ; dynamic features;fast and local loadings,updating;

Comment: $.ajax({type:"GET",url:"go.php",data:{'snf_sil':e},success: function(e){ okey here code ;}});